# Show only li and corresponding elements that contain visible and hidden text matching search terms?

Tags: search, filter, html-lists, show-hide

I have this:

```
<ul id="container">  
  <li class="sub_container">  
    <a> + text + </a><span> + text + </span><span> + text + </span>  
    <span> + text + </span><a> + text + </a><div> + text + </div>  
    <hr></hr>  
  </li>
  <li class="sub_container">  
    <a> + text + </a><span> + text + </span><span> + text + </span>  
    <span> + text + </span><a> + text + </a><div> + text + </div>  
    <hr></hr>  
  </li>  
</ul>
```

and I want to be able to search some visible and hidden text (if possible), so where there is a matching term within `+ text +` inside any `<li>` tags, only those relevant tags and all their contained elements (which also includes their `+ text +`) stay visible while all other `<li>` and contained elements become hidden. Shown above is a sample set of two `<li>` and their contained elements but those tags and elements will multiply dynamically - only the content of `+ text +` changes (`+ text +` parts come from spreadsheet).

I tried this for searching, where `#find` is a link to activate the search and `#filter` is the input box to type the search terms:

```
$jq("#find").click(function(){
  $jq("ul li").hide()
  .filter(":contains('"+ $jq("#filter").val() +"')").show()
  return false;
})
```

It works but hides only the next 2 items (in this case an `<a>` and `<span>`) located immediately after the opening `<li>` tag. I tried this plugin at http://lomalogue.com/jquery/quicksearch/ but it gave no results. Any simple click function like the above would be appreciated. Thx ahead for guiding me with a working sample.

Comment: `$jq(document).ready(function(){
$jq("#find").click(function() {
$jq(".expandable").filter(":contains('"+ $jq("#search").val() +"')").show("fast");
$jq(".expandable:not(:contains('"+ $jq("#search").val() +"'))").hide("fast");
});
});` is what I managed so far to hide a div class within `<li>`s with negative search results, but the rest of `<li>`s and their contained elements are still visible. Basically, all `<li>`s must hide if any text enclosed by the elements which are enclosed by the `<li>`s do not match search terms.

Answer (score 0):

This parcel of code finally helped:

```
$jq("span.numbers, div.timestamp, span.title, div.text, hr").hide();
$jq(".text:containsIgnoreCase("+ $jq(".search").val() +")").show("fast");
$jq(".text:containsIgnoreCase("+ $jq(".search").val() +")").prev("span").show("fast");
$jq(".text:containsIgnoreCase("+ $jq(".search").val() +")").prev("span").prev("div").show("fast");
$jq(".text:containsIgnoreCase("+ $jq(".search").val() +")").prev("span").prev("div").prev("span").show("fast");
$jq(".text:containsIgnoreCase("+ $jq(".search").val() +")").next("hr").show("fast");
```

The above code hides all elements and *then* shows elements matching search terms, I guess you could do it the other way around. The headers and other items (siblings related to and located above the divs containing the search terms) display accordingly. This works great for dynamically inserted data coming from a spreadsheet, for instance, where `#id`s cannot be used and each section of data utilizes the same `.class` elements.